# How can I get correct COLLATE clause with Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script of MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2.5.0 build 397 (32bits).

I have a table which is something like the following screenshot:

[image]

Note that I've specified `utf8mb4 - utf8mb4_bin` as Collation that supposed to be used in SQL that will be produced by `Export => Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script`. But it doesn't work as I expected. It produces the definition of column as follows:

```
  `idtable1` VARCHAR(16) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
```

This is not what I want. I want the following one instead:

```
  `idtable1` VARCHAR(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
```

How can I get that? Do I have any missing settings for Workbench?

Comment: Can you try with the latest version instead (6.3.5 atm)?

Comment: Hi, I've just tried 6.3.5 build 201 CE (64 bits) but unfortunately it produces the same one as 6.2.5.0 build 397.

Comment: It looks like a similar problem is already filed as a bug but not fixed yet. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78817